# Transformation matrix - is it also orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

This question came up while I was reading some theory about
quadratic forms and about transforming them into their canonical forms.
I am reading it is also related to transforming 2nd degree curves/surfaces to principal axes.

Anyway, this is just some context. Here is the question.

The matrices below are with real numbers.

Suppose $A,B$ are orthogonal matrices and $T$ is an invertible matrix such that

$B = T^{-1}AT$

From just that, does it follow that $T$ is also an orthogonal matrix?

I can't seem to prove it so my guess is that this conclusion is not true. But I am not fully sure.

Comment: Your guess is right. Can you see what happens when $A=B=I?$

Comment: If $A=B$ and $T$ is any multiple of the identity matrix ($T=aI$) matrix, then $$B=T^{-1}AT$$ is satisfied, but $T$ does not need to be othogonal.

Comment: No. Let A and B be the identity. Any T conjugates A to B.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone. Is there any example where A,B are not both equal to the identity matrix?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, take any orthogonal matrix $A$ and put $T=2I$, for instance. Then $T^{-1}AT = A$ and $|\det T| \neq 1$.